# Как закрыть по клику предыдущий ответ?

Tags: javascript, php

В общем при нажатии на название вопроса должен открываться ответ. Это-то сделал.
Но нужно сделать так, чтобы предыдущий ответ закрывался.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{
?>
<script language="javascript">
function <? echo 'opis_'.$row['id'].''; ?> () {
    var ele = document.getElementById("<?echo'opiss_'.$row['id'].'';?>");
    var text = document.getElementById("<?echo'opis_view_'.$row['id'].'';?>");
    if (ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "<?echo'<u>'.$row['name'].'</u>';?>";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "<?echo'<b><u>'.$row['name'].'</u></b>'?>";
    }
}
</script> 
<?
echo '<span style="color:#669a00;">' . $row['id'] . '.</span> <a href="javascript&#058;opis_' . $row['id'] . '();" id="opis_view_' . $row['id'] . '"><u>' . $row['name'] . '</u></a><br/>';
echo '<div id="opiss_' . $row['id'] . '" style="border: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;overflow: auto;margin: 6px;border-radius:5px;padding:3px;display: none;"><div class="text">';
echo $row['text'];
echo '</div></div>';
echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: sergiks не работает он.

Answer (score 1):

Экий бардачный код.. Это на каждую строку выводить свой JS?! — ужос! Изыди.

Как надо.

1. использовать JS фреймворк, напр. jQuery - чтобы был простой и понятный скрипт, работающий во всех браузерах;
2. логика JS такая: по клику прячем все ответы, показываем только наш.
3. выводи строки, давая им уникальные ID - это всё, что требуется от php;
4. используй шаблоны, чтобы код был читаемым.
5. стили - классами и внешним CSS;

Примерно PHP:

```
$tmpl = <<<EOFHTML
<div id="%s" class="item">
    <h4>%s</h4>
    <div>%s</div>
</div>
EOFHTML;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $req)) {
    printf( $tmpl, $row['id'], 4row['name'], $row['text']);
}
```

И примерно JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.item > h4').click( function(){
        $('.item > div').each( function() { this.hide(); });
        $(this).parent().find('div').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: либо 

     $('.item > div').each( function() { $(this).hide(); });

но лучше
     
      $('.item > div').hide();

Comment: Что-то не работает.

Comment: @Rules пустая строка до, 4 пробела перед кодом, пустая строка после.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov: верно, в спешке писал. Спасибо!
@Rules: в обратных апострофах? `super();`
@vitagame: и не должно, это примерный код. Учитесь самостоятельно отлаживать JS и PHP - смотреть как работает, и что происходит.

Comment: Скрытие ответа то работает.
А вот как правильно прописать событие клика по названию вопроса?

Comment: $('.item > h4').click( .. )

Эта строка как раз вешает слушателя на событие клика на каждый <h4> внутри любого элемента класса `item`. Вот дока jQuery про это: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Вот так открываются все ответы
<code>$('.item > h4').click(function () {
      $('.item > div').slideDown();
    });</code>

Comment: Да, так открываются все ответы. Потому что slideDown() открывает. Все.

А так открывается только кликнутый ответ - в контексте клика по h4:

    $(this).parent().find('div').slideDown();

Пожалуйста, больше времени пробуй и думай сам, не спеши спрашивать тут.

Comment: Так работает. Но другие ответы не сворачиваются.

Comment: См. мой исходный ответ. Там вообще-то две строчки по нажатию.
Одна скрывает все ответы. Другая затем раскрывает кликнутый.

— Сынок, смотри, это море!

— Гдэ?...

Comment: Спасибо @Yura Ivanov за обучение разметке коммнетариев